# unable to connect to ssh server in LAN

Tags: centos, ssh

I've been setting up a centos 7 server as a torrent downloader and plex viewing. I've configured both properly, and both can be accessed from within the LAN (Plex is even accessible from the internet).

Suddenly, my ssh connection dropped and I haven't been able to connect to the server again. Both services are still up and running, and I've tried all these remove /etc/ssh/ssh_host* files and such, but I have been fruitless. I still can run properly ssh cantolin@localhost as root and login. Of course, sshd is up and running, and firewall-cmd has been configured already (and it wrked properly until now)

when running ssh from windows with -vvv flags I get this

```
[Modesto.Modesto-pc] ➤ ssh cantolin@192.168.1.30 -vv
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.30 [192.168.1.30] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.30:22 as 'cantolin'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection reset by 192.168.1.30
```

I can't share my sshd_config as the only way of accessing the server is a java applet powered by HP's ILO4, so no copy-paste, but I've only disallowed root login, successfully (can't login as root from localhost at least).

As of now I've depleted my google-fu reserves and my new sources of information are russian and chinese websites. Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

edit: as of now I've only set up password auth so no public/private keys for me yet

Comment: Restore the original sshd_config file.

Comment: is there a backup anywhere? if not, I already tried installing and reinstalling a couple of times, which seems to reset the config

Comment: There's the backup that you should have made before editing the file. Beyond that, reinstalling it would be a good start.

Comment: I already ran 'yum remove openssh-server' 'yum install openssh-server' a couple of times, without result. I reset the service each time too.